# Control the title and the min/max values of the colorscale for heatmaps

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap, r-plotly

I have the following R code:

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 12), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys")
p
```

The colorscale range is set by default to minimum and maximum value of the given matrix (in my example 0 to 12). Do you know how to proceed to set the values to min= -20 and max =+20.
Also, do you know how to add title on top of the colorbar?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys") %>% 
  colorbar(limits = c(-20,20), title = "TITLE")
```

The title is small. You can increase the font:

```
colorbar(limits = c(-20,20), title = "TITLE", titlefont = list(size=20))
```

You can put some HTML in the title, e.g. to have an italic title:

```
colorbar(limits = c(-20,20), title = "<em>TITLE</em>", titlefont = list(size=20))
```

You can also change the font family:

```
colorbar(limits = c(-20,20), title = "TITLE", titlefont = list(size=20, family="Arial"))
```

See [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar-title) for details and more options.